# TypeScript: Generate type or interface of enum values

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, enums

I'd like to have an interface generated out of the values of an enum. I have the following use-case in React:

I have an enum with potentially a lot of key value pairs. Each of the enum values is used as form IDs, so I get the name and the value of the input element in an event listener. I'd like to set the state to `this.setState({ name: value })`, but the name, description, etc. should be type-safe.

So I somehow need to generate an interface out of the values of the enum (because an interface cannot inherit from an enum) to be able to do the following for example: `this.setState({ name: 'hello world' })` and `this.setState({ description: 'a description' })`

```js
enum InputIDs {
    NAME = 'name',
    DESCRIPTION = 'description',
    // ... many more items ...
}

interface IMyReactComponentState {
    alreadyExisting: boolean;
    [InputIDs.NAME]: string;
    // ... all other items from the Test enum should go here but I'd like to generate it somehow ...
}

class MyReactComponent extends React.Component< ISomeProps, IMyReactComponentState > {
    constructor(props: ISomeProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            alreadyExisting: false,
            [InputIDs.NAME]: '',
            // more default values
        }
    }

    private handleChange = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
        // TODO make type safe
        const {name, value}: {name: any, value: string} = (event.target as any); // event.target is either HTMLInputElement, HTMLSelectElement or HTMLTextAreaElement

        // store the value of the corresponding input in state to preserve it when changing tabs
        this.setState({
            [name]: value
        });
  }

}
```

My problem is that something along these lines is not possible:

```
interface IMyReactComponentState extends InputIDs {
    alreadyExisting: boolean;
}
```

Any ideas how I can keep the enum with the typings of IMyReactComponentState in sync without writing an interface myself?

Thanks in advance! Not sure if this has been asked already - if so I haven't found the answer yet!

---

**EDIT (May 8th, 2019):**

We're using TypeScript 2.8.1 in our project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an interasection and a mapped type (the predefined `Record` mapped type should do)

```
enum InputIDs {
    NAME = 'name',
    DESCRIPTION = 'description',
    // ... many more items ...
}

type IMyReactComponentState = {
    alreadyExisting: boolean;
} & Record<InputIDs, string>

class MyReactComponent { // simplified
    state:IMyReactComponentState
    constructor() {        
        this.state = {
            alreadyExisting: false,
            [InputIDs.NAME]: '',
            [InputIDs.DESCRIPTION]: ''
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) to produce type with enum values as a keys, then use [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) or extend it with additional properties:

```
type InputValues = {
    [key in InputIDs]: string
}
```

Then

```
type IMyReactComponentState = InputValues & {
    alreadyExisting: boolean
};
```

Or:

```
interface IMyReactComponentState extends InputValues {
    alreadyExisting: boolean
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your IMyReactComponentState as

```
interface IMyReactComponentState {
    alreadyExisting: boolean;
    [key in keyof typeof InputIDs]: string 
}
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response. then I get the following error `']' expected.ts(1005)
unused expression, expected an assignment or function calltslint(no-unused-expression)` (I added a semicolon in the second line of the interface, although I think they're not needed in the last definition)